# How to make spinner like actionbar in native android

Tags: android, android-widget, android-actionbar, android-spinner, android-theme

After using Actionbar i thought that what if same widget could be available for native android platform.
I dont know if we can grab the styles and apply it to native widgets from actionbar apis(compatibility library v4) or not.

What i am asking is spinner widget like below which is mostly used in actionbar.

[image]

Check for dropdown widget.

Is it possible to use the same in native like in Listview  ?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArrayList);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Set DropDownViewResource will work

What's more:
In your layout file
Add the follow code for your Spinner

`style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Light.Spinner"`

Comment: Hi,
As i set style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Light.Spinner" in layout file it went to similar for what i have asked.But it didn't look same when i run the application in emulator.
Can you say what is missing ?